# Combinatorics president and votes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 5 candidates for presidency and 11 people that can vote at most one of them (so they can decide not to vote). How many combinations of votes are there if no candidate can recieve more than 5 votes?

To explain better I make an example:
if the candidates are $A,B,C,D,E$ then 
the votes $A-2,B-3,C-1$ are different to $A-3,B-2,C-1$.

EDIT: I will add the solution I just received to ask you for explanations.

Before counting the total number of ways to distribute 11 votes among 5, it adds a "dummy candidate" that will receive the remaining votes (of who didn't voted) and calculates $\binom{6+11-1}{11}=\binom{16}{11}=4368$.

Then it substracts $\binom{5}{1}\binom{6+5-1}{5}=1260$ for the resulting $3108$ combinations.

Can someone explain me this steps please? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: Maybe it's clear now

Comment: Please share your efforts.

Comment: What is a "combination of votes?".  If the candidates are $A,B,C,D,E$ is $A-5, C-2, D-1$ different from $B-5,C-1,E-2$?

Comment: I made an example, it's different

Answer (score 1):

Counting down from all $11$ voting to none voting,
without any other restrictions, stars and bars will give $\binom{15}4 + \binom{14}4 + .... + \binom44$ ways

To take into account that no one gets more than $5$ votes, we "pre-place" $6$ votes for any of the five candidates, and subtract all such cases, viz. $5\left[\binom94 + \binom84 + .... \binom44\right]$

**PS**

I agree that the answer you were given (adding a dummy candidate) is a slicker way of arriving at the solution.

Btw, I have just realised that the solution I arrived at transforms *immediately* into
$\binom{16}{5} - 5\binom{10}{5}$ using the famous **hockey stick identity** (Do look it up ! It simplifies many difficult problems immensely!)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_k$ denote the number of votes received by the $k$th candidate.  Since one or more of the eleven eligible voters may not vote, the number of votes the candidates receive satisfies the inequality
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \leq 11 \tag{1}$$
Let $a$ denote the number of people who abstain from voting.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + a = 11 \tag{2}$$
which is an equation in the non-negative integers equivalent to inequality 1 since 
$$a = 11 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)$$
A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to placing five addition signs in a row of eleven ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 + 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 4$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 2$, $x_5 = 1$, and $a = 0$, while
$$1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 5$, $x_4 = 2$, $x_5 = 0$, and $a = 3$.

Thus, the number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways five addition signs can be inserted in a row of eleven ones, which is 
$$\binom{11 + 5}{5} = \binom{16}{5}$$
since we must choose which five of the sixteen symbols (five addition signs and eleven ones) will be addition signs.

We still have to take into account the observation that no candidate received more than five votes.  We must remove those solutions of equation 2 in which at least one of the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ exceeds $5$.  Suppose $x_1 > 5$.  Let $y_1 = x_1 - 6$.  Then $y_1$ is a non-negative integer.  If we substitute $y_1 + 6$ for $x_1$ in equation 2, we obtain
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 6 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + a & = 11\\
y_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + a & = 5 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the non-negative integers with $\binom{5 + 5}{5} = \binom{10}{5}$ solutions.  However, any of the five candidates could have received more than five votes, so the number of solutions of equation 2 in which one of the variables exceeds $5$ is 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{5}$$
Since $2 \cdot 6 = 12 > 11$, it is not possible for two or more of the candidates to receive more than five votes.

Hence, the number of ways the $11$ people eligible to vote could distribute their votes to the five candidates if each voter votes for at most one candidate and no candidate receives more than five votes is 
$$\binom{16}{5} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{5}$$